# request.POST parameters are missing

Tags: python, django, django-views, request

Hello I am trying to pass some values from my signup form to a django view but for some reason the values are missing.

 My **view.py** :

```py
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):

   if request.method =='POST':
       for key, value in request.POST.lists():
           print(" DEBUG %s %s" % (key, value))
       print(request.POST['name'],email=request.POST['email'])
   return render(request, 'front_app/login.html')
```

My **register.html** :

```html
 <form class="form" method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}" name="submitForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" required>
    <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
    <div>
    <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password (8 characters minimum)" id="password" minlength="8" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register" >
  </form>
```

and my **urls.py** :

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # other not related urls
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    ]
```

My problem is that when the views.signup function is running it is missing all three values that I am trying to send : name, email and password.

It is a POST request (and not GET) but the only values in the QueryDict are the "encoding" and "csrfmiddlewaretoken" values. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because the other `input`s have no `name`s associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Selcuk comment,

The request.POST data is a dict filled with the name of the input fields of the HTML form.

Try with :

```
 <form class="form" method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}" name="submitForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" required>
    <div>
    <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password (8 characters minimum)" id="password" minlength="8" name ="password" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register" >
  </form>
```

Comment: This worked , so easy but I spent hours trying to solve it before asking here . Thanks